# Change a tuple using pig

Tags: tuples, apache-pig, udf

I need to substitute characters of a tuple using Pig UDF. For eg, if i have a line in the file as "hello world, Hello WORLD, hello\WORLD" required to be transformed as "hello_world,hello_world,hello_world". To accomplish this, i tried below UDF:

```
package myUDF;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.data.TupleFactory;
public class ReplaceValues extends EvalFunc<Tuple>
{
    public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
     try{
           String str = (String)input.get(0);
           str=str.replace(" ", "_");
           str=str.replace("/","");
           str=str.replace("\\","");
           TupleFactory tf = TupleFactory.getInstance();
           Tuple t = tf.newTuple();
           t.append(str);
           return t;
    }catch(Exception e){
        throw new IOException("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
    }
  }
}
```

but when calling this UDF via pig script i am facing issues, please help me in resolving this:

```
A = load '/user/cloudera/Stage/ActualDataSet.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS (Rank:chararray,NCTNumber:chararray,Title:chararray,Recruitment:chararray);
B = FILTER A by Rank == 'Rank';
C = FOREACH B GENERATE PigUDF.ReplaceValues(B);
```

Error: Pig script failed to parse: 
 Invalid scalar projection: B : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Comment: UDF Code:
public class ReplaceValues extends EvalFunc<Tuple>
{
   public Tuple exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
       if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
         String str = (String)input.get(0);
            str=str.replace(" ", "_");
            str=str.replace("/","");
            str=str.replace("\\","");
            TupleFactory tf = TupleFactory.getInstance();
            Tuple t = tf.newTuple();
            t.append(str);
           return t;
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw(e);
        }
    }
  }

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the field that you are trying to modify and not the relation B.Assuming the field that you are trying to match is Title, then you would call the UDF like below

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE B.Rank,B.NCTNumber,PigUDF.ReplaceValues(B.Title),B.Recruitment;
```

Note that if you are trying to replace it in the entire record then your load statement is incorrect.You will have to load the entire record as one `line:chararray` and then pass the `line` to your UDF.

Also, instead of an UDF you can use `REGEX` to match and replace the string of your choice.

Comment: Thanks for you inputs. My plan was to send whole tuple (in this case Title,NCTNumber, Recuitment...) and get the cleansed output from UDF. That was the reason the return type for exec method as tuple, else we can use String to do so. Is there a way to avoid multiple calls to UDF for each value of tuple?. Also, i thought of using REGEX/ REPLACE using pig commands, but i was not able to find right syntax to replace "\" (backslash).

Answer (score 0):

In your Pig script, you are passing entire Bag "**B**" in the UDF, while it accepts tuple as an argument.

Instead pass the field like B.Title as given below.

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE PigUDF.ReplaceValues(B.Title);
```

you can call this UDF on other fields also in the same line as:

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE PigUDF.ReplaceValues(B.Title), PigUDF.ReplaceValues(B.Rank);
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, i am new to this technology. I was using EvalFunc<Tuple>, does it mean i am sending a tuple but not the bag? My plan was to cleanse who line at one go rather that calling UDF for each data member of a tuple

Comment: You can't send a bag in [EvalFunc()](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/EvalFunc.html#exec(org.apache.pig.data.Tuple)). It takes only Tuple as input but output can be DataBag.  In your case, you are filtering the records on Rank, so you can load remaining 3 tuples as 1 tuple and pass it to UDF, otherwise you will have to pass one by one.  Please refer [EvalFunction post](https://wiki.apache.org/pig/EvalFunction) for more details

Comment: Thanks Nishu. So are you saying that I need to call UDF as                        C = FOREACH B GENERATE PigUDF.ReplaceValues(Title,Rank,....) to pass lines as tuple, but not as (B). Also can you provide the pig command to replace "\" (backslash)?